# trigger does not work for a specific table postgres 11

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

```
: LOG:  process 79596 still waiting for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 323059106 of database 16402 after 3005.513 ms

: DETAIL:  Processes holding the lock: 83081, 83080, 83083, 83082, 62764, 37865, 39707. Wait queue: 79596, 95326.

: STATEMENT:  -- Trigger: my_trigger
    
    DROP TRIGGER my_trigger ON public.payments_log;
    
    CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER my_trigger
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON payments_log
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION my_trigger_function();
```

The trigger is created, but does not work. Message when creating.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that it was a partition table. And in fact, nothing was written there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).